# How to set for loop value all to 0 in MVC C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this IdNo which contains 2letter and 7 digit just like how our identity card number.
The following code is in an Else statement whereby I have to do a loop to count characters because this it might no be necessarily 9 characters i might be more.

```
for(int j=0;j<idNo.Length;j++)
{
   what to put here?
   to set the 9 character to 0??    
}
;
```

Comment: `idNo="000000000"`? Maybe show what you have tried?

Comment: yes :)... why to write an extra line for that , when you can do it simply .

Comment: How the final outpt may looks like?

Comment: @xSea - why do you want to loop, just assign the value as 000000000. if you are default it to all zero.

Comment: @xSea I hope the  idNo is a string variable. if in that case , you can directly assign the value as zero. no need for looping.

Comment: Because i have IF else statement and this is under else statement whereby i have to count the number of characters might not necessary be 9 characters

Comment: Maybe you can show us the whole section (if-else), example input and expected output?

Comment: So you want a string with 0 based on how long the idNo is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
string zeroes= new String('0', idNo.Length);
```

basically what it is, the '0' is the character you with to repeat inNo.Lengths times

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correct, you have a given string, but it's length can differ. Then you try to replace every character (letters and digits) in this string with `0`.

```
public static string AllCharsToZeros(string s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        s[i] = "0";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

May this will do the trick for you without any loops. And even if you dont know how many characters count would it be.

```
ToString().PadRight(idNo.Length,'0');
```

You just need to write with the string which contains your first 2 characters of ID. Like for example.

```
string sm = "AB";
string urid = sm.ToString().PadRight(idNo.Length,'0'));
```

or

```
string urid = sm.ToString().PadRight(idNo.Length - 2,'0'));
```

Since you wanted the length should be equal to `idNo.Length` which includes your first two chars.